# EGF coefficients in sage

Tags: combinatorics, sage

To extract coefficients from an ordinary generating function in sage I do it this way

```
sage: var('z')
z
sage: T=-1/2*(sqrt(-4*z + 1) - 1)/z
sage: T.series(z,101).coefficient(z,100)
896519947090131496687170070074100632420837521538745909320
```

The above gives us the coefficient 100 of the OGF $-\frac{\sqrt{1-4z}-1}{2z}$ (which is the right solution for $T(z)=1+z\cdot T(z)^2$). However there is an easier way to do it, that is using `Lazy Power Series`

```
sage: L.<z> = LazyPowerSeriesRing(QQ)
sage: T =  L()
sage: T._name = 'C'
sage: T.define (1+z*T^2)
sage: T.coefficient(100)
896519947090131496687170070074100632420837521538745909320
```

My problem is the following, I want to extract coefficients from the EGF $\displaystyle e^{e^z-1}$ and using the first method if it works

```
sage: var('z')
z
sage: F=exp(exp(z)-1)
sage: F.taylor(z,0,21).coefficient(z,20)
263898766507/12412765347840000
```

My question is, how do I extract coefficients using `F.coefficient(20)` since in this case `LazyPowerSeriesRing` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why working with the `Lazy` constructor?! I tried in a similar manner

```
sage: PREC = 30    # use a higher precision then the needed coefficient(s)
sage: L.<z> = PowerSeriesRing(QQ, default_prec=PREC)
sage: L
Power Series Ring in z over Rational Field
sage: L.default_prec()
30
sage: F = exp( exp(z) - 1 )
sage: F.coefficients()[:6]
[1, 1, 1, 5/6, 5/8, 13/30]
sage: F.coefficients()[20]
263898766507/12412765347840000
```

and the needed coefficient was reproduced. To be concrete:

```
sage: L.<z> = PowerSeriesRing(QQ, default_prec=30)
sage: F =exp( exp(z) - 1 )
sage: F.coefficients()[20]
263898766507/12412765347840000
```